# cannot download Spacenet-dataset from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to download [spacenet dataset](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/public-data-sets/spacenet/) from AWS S3.
I type:

```
aws s3 sync s3://spacenet-dataset .
```

Then, I  get:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

Why cannot I access the bucket?
But the website says that it can be available with no cost.

Anyone can help?
Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page you linked it says:

> The spacenet-dataset S3 bucket is provided as a Requester Pays bucket,
>   see here for more information.

That means you have to [pay](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html) the S3 costs to download the data.

Comment: I tried: ` s3cmd get --recursive --skip-existing s3://spacenet-dataset --requester-pays`  and it came out: `ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden)` What is the reason? I am new to aws s3. Thank you.

Comment: It works when I use: s3cmd --requester-pays get s3://

Comment: @karl_TUM Since you're new to AWS, be wary of how much it could cost you to download the datasets. https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: What? I downloaded the dataset without paying. Is the owner of the dataset who pays, not you.

Comment: Indeed, the link you provided says "storage pricing", not downloading pricing...

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your aws user account has permissions to access s3.

I added the policy 'AmazonS3FullAccess' to a new group, and put my user in that group, all done through the IAM service on AWS

Run `aws -configure` to configure the aws client, then you can download a file like this:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset --key manifest.txt --request-payer requester manifest.txt
```

Or you can get the 3-band chipper imagery:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset --key AOI_1_Rio/processedData/3band.tar.gz --request-payer requester 3band.tar.gz
```